# Kilo as 1 024, Mega as 1 048 576

Tags: abbreviations

Under SI, the *kilo* prefix refers to 1,000 and mega refers to 1,000,000. In strict computer terms, *kilo* refers to 1,024 (2<sup>10</sup>), *mega* refers to 1,048,576 (2<sup>20</sup>) and *giga* is 1,073,741,824 (2<sup>30</sup>).

The original question was how widely known outside this domain is this distinction?

Going by the answers provided, I should be using binary prefixes in order to remove the ambiguity in my documentation.

Comment: The question is: what is your *answerable* question?

Comment: Agree with @jae. You need to reformulate this question. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: Last time that I counted, 1M people (1,000,000).

Comment: I'll second @jae. If your question is really "how many", I'm afraid we can't reliably answer that. And even if it's more like "are there many", that's quite subjective still.

Comment: All the answers — all possible answers — are subjective; this question is really a near-canonical example of "subjective and argumentative". I vote to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not many.  At least that’s presumed — by the people who then invented *Kibi* and *Mebi* and *Gibi*.  Yup, there’s sort-of (I don’t deign to honor them as) SI prefixes: kB is kilobytes, that is, 1000 bytes (some used “KB” to signify 2<sup>10</sup> bytes, but that’s really nonstandard).  While kiB, kibibytes, is 1024 bytes.

Likewise for MB -> MiB (Mebibytes) and GB -> Gibibytes.

The *bi* here stands for binary, so the long longform could be *Kilobinarybytes*.  It’s all weird anyway.

I guess one could presume that even fewer people “outside the domain” are aware of those new binary prefixes than were aware of the old power-of-two one, if you consider that even people *inside* said domain are unaware of those new prefixes.

Comment: Not to mention that few people in general know about the SI prefixes. :D

Comment: It's all a scam by hard drive manufacturers anyway!

Comment: @Eric sort-of.  They did use the precise SI definition of the prefixes when it was generally (in the field) understood that K, M etc were power-of-two prefixes, which the (desired) effect to make HDs looks bigger than they "actually" were.  The "binary" prefixes are an attempt to work around that.  An apparently failed one.

Comment: False. Even in the computer industry how much 1 kilohertz means (1000 hertz), or how much 1 megabit-per-second means (1000000 b/s). If you look at history, the hard-drive manufacturers were using kilo/mega correctly (powers of 1000) even before the RAM people came up with their powers-of-1024 abuse of terminology. The new prefixes, increasing in popularity, are hopefully a way of both resolving confusion, and (because they are so awkward :p) discouraging the powers-of-1024 units that users don't need to be bothered with. (It's happening slowly: already Mac OS X uses decimal units.)

Answer (score 13):

Not so many. Most people within the computer domain aren't even aware of all the details.

The slightly larger kilo unit actually have gotten it's own unit, or actually a set of units. 1024 bytes is one [kibibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte), 1024 kibibyte is one mebibyte, and so on.

Even within the computer domain, both types of units are used. Disk storage manufacturers for example uses 1000 as kilo to measure disk sizes, while operating systems uses 1024 as kilo to measure disk usage. That means that a 2.0 terabyte disk only has room for 1.82 terabyte data. (Also, as some of the space is used to keep track of the data on the disk, the actual amount that you can store on the disk is even less.)

Even disk manufacturers aren't consistent, and both units has even been mixed to measure the size of a single type of disk. The (once) so well known 1.44 megabyte 3.25" floppy disk is actually neither 1.44 megabyte nor 1.44 mebibyte. It's actually 1.44 * 1000 * 1024 bytes, or 1.44 kilo-kibi-byte...

Comment: In my opinion, if people wanted these binary-based units to actually catch on, they should have — at the very least — consulted their own internal linguistic intuition and realized that "kibibyte" and "mebibyte" are awkward (or even silly) sounding and quite difficult to articulate properly in rapid speech.  They probably thought that the *-bi-* part would relate to the fact that it is binary, but come on: people are supposed to actually speak these words!

Comment: "while operating systems uses 1024 as kilo to measure disk usage"  Microsoft Windows does, but Mac OS X and Ubuntu have both converted to follow the standards.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: *gibibyte* sounds more silly than *gigabyte*?  No, you're just used to it.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is not many.  That's why there is an increasing move to refer to use "kibi", "mebi" and so on as prefixes for these powers of two.  Wikipedia has an article about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Answer (score 4):

Umm, not very many? The computer definitions aren't much use outside computer stuff, so I'd say that the vast majority of non-computer people are ignorant of the distinction (or don't care enough to remember it).

But really, I could guess at numbers all day. How on Earth would we know the answer to this?

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of how many people know or don't know about it, if you're writing a specification or technical publication, my suggestion is to use the binary prefixes (*kibi, mebi*), that way there is no room for ambiguity.

Comment: That, or at the beginning of the document state which kind of kB/MB/GB you are talking about

Comment: @Mr. Shiny, that's also a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, *kilo-*, *mega-*, etc. are *ambiguous*, because some think they ought to be based on powers of 2 in a computing context and powers of 10 otherwise, some disagree, and both sides just go ahead and use what they prefer. To solve this, the prefixes *kibi-* (2<sup>10</sup>), *mebi-* (2<sup>20</sup>), *gibi-* (2<sup>30</sup>), and *tebi-* (2<sup>40</sup>) have been introduced; these I find are rarely used in whole form, but there's increasingly common use of their abbreviations KiB, MiB, GiB, and TiB. I for one always say "K", "meg", "gig", and "terabyte".

The Wikipedia entry on [binary prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) sums up the issues nicely.

Comment: Well, even "computing context" isn't quite it… within the computer context, people consistently use 1 kilohertz to mean 1000 hertz, 1 megabit-per-second to mean 1000000 b/s. It's only when it comes to measuring *bytes*, somehow, that some people are attached to the abuse of terminology of kilo meaning 1024.:-) Apart from kibi-/mebi-/gibi- etc. being used, there's also (thankfully) some user-friendly software that use the standard prefixes in the same senses that people are familiar with from all other aspects of their life (i.e., kilo meaning 1000 etc.): Mac OS X 10.6, apt-get, fdisk, gparted…

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: True, though it makes sense to talk about kilohertz as 1000 Hz because there's no sensible reason for a second to be multiplied by or divided into 1024, whereas I'd argue that all measurements of bit *and* byte sizes should be done in powers of two, as binary is the basis of our modern computing systems. Then again, user-interface-wise, decimal is obviously the superior usability choice.

Comment: @Jon: "Binary is the basis of our modern computing systems" is, again, the same sort of thing that's true only in restricted contexts. (After all, don't clocks and data transfer have something to do with the "our modern computing systems" as well?) The fact is, unlike RAM which was built on binary trees (having to do with addressing: that's why 32-bit, 64-bit), **hard disks are not built on binary trees.** So there is no reason to measure hard disk space in powers of two. Besides, as you said, normal users don't have to be tortured with binary even some things internally happen in binary. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: The engineering prefixes are setup for 3-digit groups on the decimal base.  Computer memory calculations are always in powers of two, being binary in nature, so they adapted the engineering prefixes a very very long time ago to work with binary powers instead, (2^8)^1 being used for kilo, (2^8)^2 for mega, and so forth.  It is an appropriation for convenience and all operatives within the domain until recently were well aware of this.  Now people are just confused, due to too much switching, the "bi" tag being pretty much a failure outside of educated circles.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It is to do with memory addressing modes that binary is used, the internal mechanisms of the hardware work entirely in binary.  Decimal within computers is just there as a conversion for the users convenience.

Comment: @Orbling: As I said, it is only with memory addressing (having to do with memory, not disk) that binary of any relevance, and besides, whatever is used internally, there is no reason to confuse users with made-up abuse of terminology. There were already some wise voices among the engineers who warned of the mess when they started to abuse "kilo" to mean 1024; unfortunately they were ignored, engineers continued to be hacky, and we have the mess today. :-)

Comment: @Orbling: BTW, your earlier comment illustrates the lengths to which engineers, [supposedly](http://lpar.ath0.com/2008/07/15/si-unit-prefixes-a-plea-for-sanity/) rational creatures valuing clarity, will go to defend sth they're merely used to.:-) Although 8=2^3, powers of 2^8 would be groups of 8 in binary, not of 3. Further 2^8=256, not 1024, which is 2^10—groups of 10 in binary. But it was chosen rather because it's close to 1000—groups of 3 in *decimal*—because numbers are written in decimal. And history: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_binary_prefixes (notice e.g. "65K" for 65536)

Comment: @Orbling: To repeat, memory (RAM) sizes are usually powers of 2, so it makes sense to use powers of 2 there. But *disk and file sizes may be any number of bytes*; it's just a number. There's no reason to use so-called "binary" (meaning decimal, except that some large power of 2 has been divided out) for them. The claim of "convenience" does not actually stand up to scrutiny. (How many megabytes is 1.76 gigabytes? With standard prefixes it's clear—1760 megabytes—but with the nonstandard prefixes you have to multiply by 1024; conversely (e.g) 1503 MiB=1.4873046875 GiB: too many digits! Rounding?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It may not make sense to you, I assume you are a non computer scientist.  But it makes far more sense to me to be binary.  Disks are addressed in binary mode, the same as memory, there is no real difference there, everything inside the machine is binary.  Files can be any size, yes, but they are still stored in sectors which are binary aligned.  If a disk has a sector size of 4K (4096 x 8 bits), then I want to know how much space the file is taking up in terms of those sectors.  I don't want to know the decimal alternative.  The problem with clarity is the conversion to decimal.

Comment: @Orbling: Most people aren't interested in how many sectors a file takes, but merely "how big" it is. But let's say you have your reasons. Now picking a random file on my computer, it's 10294861 bytes long. Whether it's listed as 10.3 MB (decimal) or 9.8 MB ("binary"), the information is the same: it's approx 10290000 bytes, except that in the latter it's harder to see. And if you want the information precisely, you have to say either 10.294861 MB or 9.81794452667236328125 MB, and even here the 'binary' is more unwieldy. (BTW, by using "4096" instead of "1000000000000", you're using decimal.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You're right that decimal is better from a UI perspective, but it's an issue that makes programmers uncomfortable for a number of reasons; the back end and front end are simply at odds, and there's nothing that can be done but to pick one and go with it. Also, your "4096" comment came off as unnecessarily combative.

Comment: @Jon: I didn't mean it to be combative (as probably neither did Orbling with "It may not make sense to you…"); it's just the 600-char limit.:-) My point is that the so-called binary units aren't *really* binary; we *are* using decimal everywhere: even the reason for defining "kilo" etc as powers of 2^10 is precisely because it leads to convenience in the *decimal* we use (1024 because it's close to 1000). Also, having done a fair bit of programming myself, in my experience, if you look carefully, there's no intrinsic reason for back-ends to use old units except in some very restricted cases.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: The point is we are using binary pretty much everywhere to do with spacial size and calculations within the computer and only presenting numbers as decimal to the user, because the user doesn't like reading binary.  I wrote 4096, because 1000000000000 is hard to digest for us, UI versus implementation as @Jon Purdy states.  Decimal is a rendering for the benefit of the user. [My "it may not make sense to you..." comment was indeed non-combative, it is just hard to explain the reasons to end-users, for whom *it is* just an inconvenience.]

Comment: @Orbling: I never said about something not making sense to me; you inserted it.:-)(As it happens, I do have a degree in computer science.) And the question of whether to define a megabyte as 1048576 or 1000000 bytes *is* precisely one of UI, for humans: the computer can deal with conversions; whether you write "10294861" or "100111010001011001001101" it's the same number. And for the sake of human convenience we not only represent numbers in decimal but make abbreviations for large numbers. The only false claim is that abbreviating large numbers as x\*(2^20) is more convenient (when, exactly)?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Apologies for implying you were not a computer scientist, I assumed from the line of your argument.  To answer that last question, it is more convenient as the memory/disk space is (or at least was before hardware manufacturers started taking advantage) in binary multiples and it is easier to handle the integer divisions of that available space than the fractional total that results from converting to another base.

Comment: @Orbling: Just because a number is divisible by 1024 doesn't mean it's divisible by 1048576, 1073741824, etc. In fact file sizes, as I showed with my actual example of a 10294861-byte file on my system, often aren't even divisible by any large power of 2 (even if you count by sectors/blocks, which is not usual). I don't even see where you get the idea of *converting* to another base: what you have is a *number*, and you divide it either by powers of 1000 or powers of 1024. You're likely to have *more* fractional digits (about thrice as many) in the latter case. Can you give an actual example?

Comment: @Orbling: And about this myth of hardware makers "taking advantage", disk sizes have never been constrained to be powers of 2 themselves (even if they are divisible by some single large power of 2). As you can check, 10294861 bytes = 10.294861 MB = 9.81794452667236328125 MiB; that's 6 digits after the decimal point using powers of 1000, and 20 digits using powers of 1024. (And an integer is integer in every base; and approximations have equivalent content whether you use 1000 or 1024.) Again, there's only the fringe case of describing the total size of a memory stick, for which 1024 is better.

Comment: Nearly all computer operating systems allocate disk space in multiples of 256 bytes.  A standard low-density 3.5" PC floppy held precisely 720*1024 bytes, and a so-called 1.44M disk held precisely twice that amount (interesting that "M" in that case means 1,024,000 bytes).  It would have seemed odd to refer to something twice the size of a 720K disk as 1.47M or 1.41M.  Flash disks are usually a power-of-two multiple of 268 bytes, of which 256 are allocated for data, but often have some bad blocks or "slack space", so useful space is a little less than a power of two.